# Auto convert all lines with only spaces to empty line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I work with Notepad++

If text file contain lines with only spaces in it - I what to auto convert (shrink) it to empty line

For example:

File before (spaces are shown as . dots, end of the line a shown as [CR][LF])

```
some code[CR][LF]
some code[CR][LF]
...[CR][LF]
some sode[CR][LF]
```

File after

```
some code[CR][LF]
some code[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
some sode[CR][LF]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Macro -> 'Trim trailing space and save' workded for me. (Alt + Shift + S)

Answer (score 0):

More recent Notepad++ versions have Menu => **Edit** => **Blank Operations** => **Trim Leading Space**. The sub menu also has **Trim Trailing Space** and **Trim Leading and Trailing Space**. See the [Notepad++ user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/#edit-menu)